# Set variable random number of dots

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set a variable random number of dots. I can generate random numbers using `Math.random()`. I tried this without any luck:

```
function generate() {

    Math.floor(Math.random() * 500)

}

var randomdots = generate();
```

What is the correct approach to set a variable random number of dots?

Comment: What are you upper and lower bounds to the number of dots you want?

Comment: In the function it generates random number. And I need to set the varieble that number of dots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use this

```
function generate() {
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
return new Array(index).join(".");
}

var randomdots = generate();
```

Answer (score 3):

This method does nothing useful, it throws away the result before using it. Maybe you want:

```js
function generate() {
  var count = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);

  var result = '';

  for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    result = result + '.';
  }

  return result;
 }

 document.write(generate());
```

Remember that functions in JavaScript *must* have a `return` if you want to get a value from them.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a JavaScript that writes bullets on page load.  Do it like this:

```js
var number = Math.ceil((Math.random() * 500)) + 1;

for (i=0;i<number;i++){
  
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += '• ';
  
  }
```

```html
<p id="output"></p>
```

Let me know if you need additional help!

Answer (score 1):

Although caslaner's answer seems to be the easiest way to achieve this, for educational purposes, here's a recursive function that does the same.

```js
function generate(str,rm) {
  if(rm === undefined) rm = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
  return rm ? generate((str||'') + '.',rm-1) : str;
}
document.write(generate());
```

Comment: Thanks for the different approach.